# Forcing a subclass to call its superclass method in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, compiler-warnings, overriding

I have two classes, `Vehicle` and `Car`; `Car` is a subclass of `Vehicle`.

There is a method `logVehicleDetail` in the `Vehicle` class.

Is there any way I can force `Car` to call its superclass method `logVehicleDetail` when overriding this method? If the subclass does not do that, then the complier should generate a warning or error.

For example, when compiling without ARC, the  compiler warns if you don't call `[super dealloc]` in your own `dealloc`.

Comment: Let me see if I got this: you want subclasses of `Vehicle` to always call `Vehicle`'s implementation of `logVehicleDetail`?

Comment: Exactly, thats what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this. Perhaps the easiest and most straightforward way would be to add `__attribute__((objc_requires_super))` to your method declaration:

```
@interface Vehicle : NSObject
  -(void)logDetails __attribute__((objc_requires_super));
@end

@implementation Car
  -(void) logDetails {
} // WARNING: Method possibly missing a [super logDetails] call
```

A different way to achieve a similar outcome would be to create a protocol for vehicles that log details e.g.

```
@protocol VehicleLogger <NSObject>

-(void)logDetails;

@end
```

in your `Vehicle` header file. Then, in every subclass of `Vehicle` that you want to log details, make it conform to that protocol.

```
@implementation Car <VehicleLogger>
```

That way, you will receive a warning in the compiler to implement that method. And in the implementation you can call `super`'s implementation of `logDetails`:

```
-(void)logDetails {
   [super logDetails];
   //Do more stuff here, if I want
}
```

If on the other hand all you want is for every subclass to call `Vehicle`'s implementation, then simply don't implement that method in the subclass.

Comment: This I know but I dont want to use this. You see Apple enforce this type of restriction. In non-arc environment if you do not call [super dealloc] then there is a warning.

Comment: In that case you can use __attribute__((objc_requires_super)) -- see my edit

Comment: The `Foundation.framework` has a macro named `NS_REQUIRES_SUPER` to replace `__attribute__((objc_requires_super))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)logVehicleDetail {
[super logVehicleDetail];
// extra implementation
}
```

Is that what you need? Or you mean you want to enforce it without having to send the super message?

Comment: I want that if subclass does not call [super logVehicleDetail] then there should be a compile time error or warning.